# Duplicate TensorFlow placeholder/variables?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I write TensorFlow code with Jupyter notebook:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name="a")
a
# <tf.Tensor 'a:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int32>
# <tf.Tensor 'a_1:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int32>
...
```

I found that if I run this cell multiple times, the name of the placeholder(variable) will be different, and it will affect the future use of these placeholders, i.e., if some other operations depend on these inputs, then I may feed values to wrong placeholders. Even if I update the future operations, the behaviors will be weird.

My question is, what is the best practice when coding TensorFlow on Jupyter in such scenarios?

Comment: tf.reset_default_graph() will reset the graph and delete any placeholders that you have previously defined